# How to display a matrix in C

Tags: c, printing, matrix

I have a matrix.txt file wherein there is a matrix written this way :

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

I need to write a little C program that take this file as input and print this matrix in the same way as the .txt file.

That means when the outpout of "./a.out matrix.txt" has to be exactly what's in my .txt file :

```
1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

My problem is that all that I can do is this function:

```
void printMatrice(matrice) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    for(x = 0 ; x < numberOfLines ; x++) {
        printf(" (");
        for(y = 0 ; y < numberOfColumns ; y++){
            printf("%d     ", matrix[x][y]);
        }
        printf(")\n");
    }
}
```

But this is not good at all.

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: "But this is not good at all." Why is it not good at all?

Comment: The output has to be exactly what's in the .txt file, but in my function I have some "(" and ")", plus a lot of spaces between them. How to print a matrix the same way I wrote it ?

Comment: Can `matrix.txt` change at all?

Comment: Nope, it has to be written this way

Comment: @Flo If you do not want parentheses, why adding them in the first place? Same goes for the extra spaces: simply remove them from your `printf`s, and you are done!

Comment: Thank you, at first I did not add any parentheses or space, but I was not able to fix it, thus I tried differently, but it did not work either

Comment: This line prints a paren:  `printf(" (");`

**If you don't want a paren, take that line out!!**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this simple code

```
int row, columns;
for (row=0; row<numberOfLines; row++)
{
    for(columns=0; columns<numberColumns; columns++)
    {
         printf("%d     ", matrix[row][columns]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified user1929959's code a little bit since I had some weird prints.
If you like you can try copy-paste this code and see how it runs. Just a n00b student here. Hope I helped a bit (I'm struggling too) ;)

## MATRIX PRINT CODE

```
void main ()
{

    int matrix [3][4] = { {1, 2, 3, 4},
                           {5, 6, 7, 8},
                           {9, 10, 11, 12}
                         };
    
    
    int row, column=0;

    for (row=0; row<3; row++)
     {
        for(column=0; column<4; column++)
            {printf("%d     ", matrix[row][column]);}
            printf("\n");
     }
    
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply what you need to add is:
put //printf("\n");
in loop,that is responsible of printing of ROWS.so that,
\n:it will change the row after complition of each row.

Answer (score 0):

here is how to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
 int matrix[3][3]={{1,2,3},
{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
int columns,rows;
for(columns=0;columns<=2;columns++){
    for(rows=0;rows<=2;rows++){
        printf(" %d " ,matrix[columns][rows]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but struggling with the same problem, I've tried to write a function for it; after some try-and-error, my solution must get its order passed as parameters; this way, it could work with any number of rows and columns:

```
void printMatrix(int row, int col, int m[raw][col]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("%d-line: ", i + 1);
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just why? How exactly I was unclear?