# My C code for 2d array creation and printing doesn't return any value

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

I have written a piece of c code which I intend to just print out the value of a 2d array

I'm very new to c so this answer might be really basic sorry.

my code compiles fine (gcc) but then doesn't return what I expect. im using ubuntu 18.04 in WSL with gcc as my compiler.

heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        int array1[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
        int i2 = 0;
        printf("hello");
        for(int i = 0; i > 4; i++){
                i2 = i;
                printf("hi %d", array1[i][i2]);

}

}
```

returned value
`hello`

i would expect it to print all my array elements but i dont understand why it doesnt since i dont get an error in gcc so my syntax seems fine.

Thanks.

Comment: You condition in `for` loop is wrong. Try `for(int i = 0; i< 3 ; ++i)`

Comment: `for` loops iterate until the condition is *false*. In your code, `i > 4` will be false as soon as the code enters the `for` loop, change it to `i < 3` or even `i <= 2` .Additionally, there is no need for the `i2` variable, it only serves to add clutter in your code, you can simply do `array[i][i]`.

Comment: just tried changing the i++ to ++i which didn't fix the problem. thanks for trying though

Comment: thanks for the tip with i2 not being necessary i have no clue why i added that. also thanks so much for the fix. i dont know how i didnt see that.

Comment: "just tried changing the i++ to ++i which didn't fix the problem". Indeed, the important part was the test modification (`>` to `<`). The `++` before `i` is just a coding tic...

Comment: Thanks for helping and fixing my problem although i have already got another one. Lol

Comment: Also check your wording / terms: your code does not `return` "hello", it prints it. Your `main` method should `return` an `int`, as you wrote `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong in this piece of code. Firstly, the usage of the column index like that (`i2 = i`) will make you print elements at the same row and column index, like `array1[0][0]`, `array1[1][1]`, and you'll skip things like `array1[0][1]`. You'd have to fix this by using a second `for` loop inside the first one, incrementing a second index (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166350/how-to-display-a-matrix-in-c/14166417) for example).
The other wrong thing about this piece of code is the condition in the `for` loop: you want to keep iterating while `i<3`, not `i>4`. In that case, you never enter the for loop, since the condition is not met even at the first iteration.

Comment: thanks! I will implement this in my next code and maybe try and make a game or something! was my i++ incorrect or why would i do ++i instead?

Comment: Good luck with that, but I'd suggest you to study some more basic concepts about C if you're new with this programming language before undertaking such a thing. For the `++i` vs `i++`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315705/what-is-the-difference-between-i-i-in-a-for-loop) out.